# Change view_mode for particular node Drupal7 (Using Rules)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-rules

I have two different view modes.

1.)Defalut

2.)Full content

Normal on the node it shows the

-Node Title

-Add to cart form.

with the "Default" view_mode.

Now after checkout process I want to change the view_mode to "Full content".

So the "User who has done the checkout for this node should get the Full Content View mode and not the Default one."

Any one having any sort of Idea?

Possibly need answer with Rules configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a View Page and choose the Full Content View Mode as display. Give the View a URL and redirect to it after checkout with Rules.